Where is this citation in the Vana Parva of the Mahabharata?
https://youtu.be/65z2bWyjfQg?t=419
This is a Hindi talk in which the speaker says (around 6:59)

(1) A faith that opposes another faith is not a faith but a heresy


(2) Only a faith that doesn't oppose any other faith is a true faith.


It is found in the Tirtha-yatra Parva Chapter 131.
धर्मं यो बाधते धर्मो न स धर्मः कुधर्म तत् ।
अविरोधी तु यो धर्मः स धर्मः सत्यविक्रम ॥


Dharma that stands in the way of another dharma is not dharma at all.
It is evil dharma (Kudharma). O one for whom valor is based on truth, Dharma that does not conflict with anything is the right Dharma.

विरोधिषु महीपाल निश्चित्य गुरुलाघवम् । 
न बाधा विद्यते यत्र तं धर्मं समुदाचरेत् ॥


O lord of the earth, when there is a conflict, you must decide in
accordance with what is important and what is unimportant. That should
be Dharma where there is no conflict.

गुरुलाघवमाज्ञाय धर्माधर्मविनिश्चये ।
यतो भूयांस्ततो राजन्कुरु धर्मविनिश्चयम् ॥


O King, after measuring the important with the unimportant and
determining what constitutes Dharma, and what does not constitute
Dharma, you must decide that to be Dharma which is weightier and act
accordingly.

Translation by B. Debroy.
